# wrong version of expo-cli after upgrade

Tags: expo

for many time i get the following info message after start expo projects, and it seems its not possible to upgrade expo-cli:

`There is a new version of expo-cli available (4.2.1). You are currently using expo-cli 3.28.0 Install expo-cli globally using the package manager of your choice; for example: npm install -g expo-cli to get the latest version`

This seems easier as it looks. After installing expo-cli globally without errors
`+ expo-cli@4.2.1`

OK, now im typing expo -V to check the new Version but wait: its 3.28.0
My project package.json dont have expo-cli in. Is there a way to locate the used expo version?

edit:

i found 1 PATH file till now.
(C:\Users\myuser.expo) it contents:

```
C:\Users\SYSTEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\yarn--1615049876273-0.687029522126771;
C:\Users\myuser\WfManager\fmapp\node_modules\.bin;
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\link\node_modules\.bin;
C:\Program Files\libexec\lib\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;
C:\Program Files\lib\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\FusionEngine;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\xampp\php;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;
C:\Program Files\Symfony;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
  C:\composer;
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

after writing this down and check the entries i found one entry which
links to an old version:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\link\node_modules\.bin; //old version

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm  //new version`
```

i want to update expo-cli with xarn global now and we will see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check path to binary with `command -v expo`.

In this case you most likely installed expo-cli globally both with npm and yarn, version `3.28.0` is just earlier in your `PATH`. It's also possible that you have two node versions (and 2 npm versions) installed, but it's less likely.

Comment: Correct Answer. There are 2 different expo-cli installs. 1 with npm and 1 with yarn. `expo start` is calling the yarn install in my case so that i have to update with `yarn global add expo-cli@4.2.1`. Solved. Thank you.